# Keep form content when close modal Ui-Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have modal use angular ui-bootstrap (I created a service). When I open modal and type some text in form and I close this modal. When I reopen it, I would like to it keep form content. Mean modal just render one time. Help me about it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data from the modal in your `controller` scope and then pass it back when the modal is opened again.

Take a look at the docs for [UI Bootstrap's Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal)

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.open = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        modalText: function() {
          return $scope.modalText;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(modalText) {
      $scope.modalText = modalText;
    });
  };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, modalText) {

  $scope.modalText = modalText;

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.modalText);
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" ng-model="modalText" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div>Text from a modal: {{ modalText }}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My mean is not store data! When close modal, it just hide, and keep scope! Any solution for me? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you saying that you do not want to close the modal you just want to hide it?

Comment: My mean is not store data, but when close modal and reopen this modal, it keep form content. Maybe it same Bootstrap modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) This is ex: http://mode87.com/untame/demo/modalcontact/

Comment: Unfortunately with the way that UI Bootstrap destroys the scope when a modal is closed, https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L393, you will need to temporarily store the data in your parent controller if you want to reload it when the modal is reopened.